# Android NoSuchMethod error

Tags: java, android, file-io, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

My app works perfect on all devices except one (LG Leon, updated to Android 6),it crashes when I try to open a stored file. I get:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Ljava/io/File;)V in class Lcom/leff/midi/MidiFile; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.leff.midi.MidiFile' appears in /system/framework/com.lge.frameworks.jar)
```

this is the constructor that gets called (with the file chosen by the user as parameter):

```
public MidiFile(File fileIn) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        this(new FileInputStream(fileIn));
    }
```

Comment: forgot to add, this worked before the update. But other devices with Android 6 work perfect too.

Comment: Is it me or this library is someone's own private work [https://github.com/LeffelMania/android-midi-lib](https://github.com/LeffelMania/android-midi-lib)and not related to Google meaning the update is not related?

Comment: I don't think the library is problematic, works perfect in all other devices.

Comment: From what it seems, LG does add the package since it takes the class from com.lge.frameworks.jar, but maybe they forgot to add the latest. Maybe it's betterif you pack it on your own

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue with a LG user with Android 9. Seems indeed that LG packages a older version that doesn't have this class or method. I suggest you shadow the library in your app to be sure you are using your own and not LGs one that takes preference. So copy the classes into your project and change package to something like com.leff_shadowed.midi and use that.

The user that had these issues reported that this change solved his problems.